# does dimensionality reduction work in similarity measures?

Tags: classification, dimensionality-reduction, cosine-similarity, cosine-distance

I'm performing classification via cosine similarity to vector means.  Normally, we reduce dimensionality of a problem in order to reduce confusion to the classifier.  Mathematically, will dimensionality reduction reduce confusion to the classifier when using a distance-based approach?  It doesn't seem like it would help, but only hurt (by withholding information.)

Thanks